# Drag and drop in relation to reparenting

Tags: x11, xlib, xcb

How can I support drag-and-drop in a reparenting window manager?

It looks like if I use an application which supports it, like thunar, and I drag it from one client to another it just goes back. I think this is because it tries to drag it into the frame window. What must I support for this to work properly? EWMH _NET_CLIENT_LIST was my first guess, and I will implement that soon, but I don't see how that will help locate the window it is being dragged to.

Man, reparenting can be a pain! It's just one person answering by now, sorry for all the questions ;)

Comment: Honest answer: I don't know. I guess a WM does not really need to do anything to specifically support DnD. However, some clients might have some expectations for things like `_NET_CLIENT_LIST`. I would claim that this would be a bug in said clients, but I am not entirely sure how DnD works either, so I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Google suggests that the relevant protocol is described in https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/XDND/

Comment: That file refers to a sample implementation which Google (possibly) found here: https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/c4ef90f5a0b1d05b16187eb6e32323defe6461c0/extern/xdnd/xdnd.c#L970-L989 This link specifically describes the code that is used to find the drop target: This is simply a loop that starts with the window containing the mouse cursor and walks up the window hierarchy until it finds a window that supports DnD. Thus, I don't even see how a WM could block/sabotage this.

Answer (score 1):

When reparenting client windows to decorations, the windows cannot be found reliably when they are not children to the root, and they also lose track of where they are in the root's coordinates.  There are two standards to implement that will cause common clients to be able to drag and drop.  They are not complex, and you can read them here:

https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html

4.1.3.1. WM_STATE Property

This will allow clients to find other clients (and themselves) even though they are not top-level windows.  For example, xprop and xwininfo will find your client window even if you click on a non-client decoration.  Here is an example:

```
    long data[2];
    data[0] = hidden ? IconicState : NormalState; // NormalState, IconicState, etc.
    data[1] = None;
    XChangeProperty(display, window, XInternAtom(display, "WM_STATE", False), 
                    XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)data, 2);
```

Next, you'll notice that the client will lose accurate ability to find where it is in the root in order to highlight and drop things.  Resizing the window may fix this, but moving the window will cause this.

4.2.3. Window Move

This will tell clients where they are in the root so they can highlight the dragged item's drop location.  Send an XConfigureEvent event using XSendEvent with the x and y in root coodinates.  Be sure to add offsets that your decoration adds.

To research this, I used xwininfo, xev, and xprop.  I noticed other window managers would allow clicks to retrieve subwindows to the decorations.  My WM did not do that.  I forked xprop and added debug output to understand what I was missing and it lead me to the standard.  Good luck!